# Angular2 test "provide => use value"

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular2-testing

I have the following code to invoke angular2

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { AppModule } from "./src/app";
export function runAngular2App(legacyModel: any) {
       platformBrowserDynamic([
           { provide: "legacyModel", useValue: model }
       ]).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
       .then(success => console.log("Ng2 Bootstrap success"))
       .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

And somewhere I am invoking it like in this manner -

```
    var legacyModel = {}; // some data
    require(["myAngular2App"], function(app) {
       app.runAngular2App(legacyModel); // Input to your APP
    });
```

**header.component.ts**
And in my component I use the legacy model -

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
  styleUrls: [ './header.less' ],
  templateUrl: './header.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
    public eventTitle;

    constructor(@Inject("appModel") private appModel) {
        this.eventTitle = this.appModel.get("eventTitle");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I am testing this component -

```
header.component.spec.ts

import {} from 'jasmine';

import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';

import { HeaderComponent } from './header.component';



describe('HeaderComponent', () => {

    let comp:    HeaderComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
    let de:      DebugElement;
    let el:      HTMLElement;

    // async beforeEach
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ HeaderComponent ] 

        })
        .compileComponents();  // compile template and css
    }));

    // synchronous beforeEach
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);

        comp = fixture.componentInstance; // HeaderComponent test instance

        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.title'));
        el = de.nativeElement;
    });

    it('should display event title', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.eventTitle);
    });

    it('should display a different event title', () => {
        comp.eventTitle = "Angular2 moderator dashboard";
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toContain("Angular2 moderator dashboard");
    });

});
```

I get the following error -

**Error: No provider for appModel! in spec.bundle.ts (line 4110)**

Since `appModel` is not service I am not able to inject it.

How do I inject appModel so my tests can run?

Answer (score 0):

Behind your implementation question appears to be an architecture question. I see the term "legacy model" -- are you trying to test a new version of a model? Does the component know how to handle both model versions? The Angular service injection pattern is not intended for models, because two different models typically have different *interfaces*, and thus are ineligible for dependency injection, which requires different implementations to have the *same* interface.

Depending on the answers to the above questions, I could imagine at least two reasonable paths forward for you:

(1) If you are indeed trying to test two versions of a model, then you should probably forget dependency injection and just use standard imports like:

```
import { AppModel } from './path/to/appModel';
import { LegacyModel } from './path/to/legacyModel';
```

Then you can test how the component responds to both model implementations.

(2) If, however, your "models" both really have the same interface, perhaps the single function I can see from your snippets:

```
get(eventTitle: string)
```

...then in that case I would introduce a new service here, and have the component invoke the service instead of the model directly. A service is an appropriate level of abstraction when you have multiple implementations, and you can have both a new and a legacy implementation of the service, injected as appropriate for your app or tests (your tests should probably test both implementations until you are ready to retire the legacy version).